# NLTK CFG ValueError: Grammar does not cover some of the input words

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, grammar, context-free-grammar

I am processing text with `nltk.ChartParser(grammar)` and get the error message as described in the headline.

I do not understand why, since all the words of my sentence are covered in the grammar, as you can see here in my code:

**1. Step: preprocessing** *(no errors)*

```
message = "The burglar robbed the bank"

import nltk
    
def preprocess(text):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)                     # sentence segmentation
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(s) for s in sentences]   # word tokenization
    sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(s) for s in sentences]         # part-of-speech tagger
    return sentences

preprocessed = preprocess(message)

print(preprocessed) # >>>> [[('The', 'DT'), ('burglar', 'NN'), ('robbed', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('bank', 'NN')]]
```

At this point, I have the sentences preprocessed and can define my grammar. It covers all the word in the example sentence as you can see here:

**2. Step: defining grammer** *(no errors)*

```
grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
NP -> DT NN
VP -> VBD NP
DT -> 'the' | 'The'
NN -> 'burglar' | 'bank'
VBD -> 'robbed'
""")
```

But executing the actual parsing results in an error:

**3. Step: parsing**

```
parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)

for sentence in preprocessed:
    for tree in parser.parse(sentence):
        print(tree)

# >>>> ValueError: Grammar does not cover some of the input words: "('The', 'DT'), ('burglar', 'NN'), ('robbed', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('bank', 'NN')".
```

I don't see why this error occurs. The words are clearly in the grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like converting the tokens to nltk.pos_tag is not quite right.
Comment that line out and the script works:

```
import nltk

message = "The burglar robbed the bank"

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Preprocessing
#----------------------------------------------------------
def preprocess(text):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)                     # sentence segmentation
    sentences = [nltk.word_tokenize(s) for s in sentences]   # word tokenization
    # THIS LINE SEEMS TO BE THE ISSUE
    # sentences = [nltk.pos_tag(s) for s in sentences]         # part-of-speech tagger
    return sentences

preprocessed = preprocess(message)

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Define grammer
#----------------------------------------------------------
grammar = nltk.CFG.fromstring("""
S -> NP VP
NP -> DT NN
VP -> VBD NP
DT -> 'the' | 'The'
NN -> 'burglar' | 'bank'
VBD -> 'robbed'
""")

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Parsing
#----------------------------------------------------------
parser = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)

for sentence in preprocessed:
    for tree in parser.parse(sentence):
        print(tree)
```

Output:

```
(S
  (NP (DT The) (NN burglar))
  (VP (VBD robbed) (NP (DT the) (NN bank))))
```